# I'm having trouble getting the express router in node js to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

The normal `get` method works fine on my main `server.js` file. I also use `server.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204));` to tackle the issue of the favicon request. It works well, again only on my main `server.js` file.
When I try to separate the code, by creating a `user.js` file that handles the api calls, I get:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 404 150 - 1.669 ms
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - GET /users HTTP/1.1 404 144 - 0.454 ms
```

This is my main file - `server.js`:

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const server = express();
    const router = require('../routes/user');
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    
    server.use(morgan('short'));
    
    //server.use(express.static('../public'));
    server.use(express.json());
    server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    
    router.use(router);
    
    server.get('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log("Test!");
        res.send("This works!");
    });  
    
    //server.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204));
    
    server.listen(3003, () => console.log('Program is running! Port: 3003'));
```

This is my `user.js` file:

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const router = express.Router();
    
    router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello');
    });
    
    router.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204));
    module.exports = router;
```

I'm not sure if this is related but I also experience the same problem when trying to `server.use(express.static('../public'))`. It doesn't work. I cannot serve my html file. I've tried using the csp headers when requesting but that doesn't work. Setting up a CSP policy in the html `header` meta tag is not working either.

These are the versions of certain modules and technologies if you see a problem in any of their versions:
Apache 2.4.39
Node 6.9.0
Windows 7 - Yeah I know but bear with me

If anyone can help with eigther the router issue or the static file server issue it would much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is, in your server.js file add

```
server.use("/user", require("./routes/routes"));
```

note: routes is a folder here and routes.js is a file inside that folder.

then in your route.js file add

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const user = require('../controllers/user.controller');

// register controllers
const userController = new user();
userController.register(router);


module.exports = router;
```

pass your router in the user register(router) method. and it will be easily accessible in your user.js file.